# Performing UI events programatically like click events in android application

Tags: android, kotlin, ui-automation

I am writing automation testing tool for UI components testing like data load validation button click validation etc.
Data load I am able to validate by automation testing application(which is running on device).
Problem is how to perform click events based on loaded data. That code should run only if automation testing is running.

Comment: Have you tried Espresso, its a good framework to test user interface.

Comment: No, but as per requirement. We have to write our automation testing tool. Is it free to use tool?

Comment: Yes, its free. It helps to perform automated click, scroll events etc while testing.